# Best mobile web video player

Tags: html5-video

I want to create mobile website with videos support. I am searching for the best video HTML5 player. It has to be fast and with youtube support (if it is possible) Thank you for your replies.

Comment: "Best" based on what criteria?

Comment: Speed is the most important. I need only h.264 playing.

Comment: Loding of player. Speed of playing hangs on device. I think...

Comment: i like video.js .. its just personal preference though, i found projekktor to be problematic

Answer (score 1):

You could try [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/), you can see a list of supported media and devices on [the specs page](http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/tech-specs/).

It comes with a HTML5 player and YouTube embedding support.